# After array items loop, re-loop them again with new data using a timer

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I have a very simple v-for array loop that grabs data from Axios and displays it in a newsreel that will show each news item, one after another, automatically. This works great, but after a few minutes it runs out of items and shows a blank div since there are only about 30 news items on the API.

**What I need**

After the v-for array runs out of items I simply want to re-run it. Fetch the API (since the API items change every 30 seconds) and then re-run the v-for array without the user having to refresh the page.

Axios call which is shown below

```
axios.get('https://myapi/news_list')
   .then(response => {
        this.news = response.data
   });
```

Template

```
<ul class="news-reel">
    <li v-for="name in news">

       <a :href="name.url">{{name.title}}</a>

    </li>
</ul>
```

** EDIT **

When I say it shows each item automatically, the ul just has a class animation that scrolls (or slides) the news items like a news marquee reel. That's all.

Comment: I'm not sure we see enough to get a good picture of what you're describing. It sounds like you're saying there's a timer somewhere, but we don't see any of that here, so it's hard to prescribe a solution.

Comment: It's just a very simple <ul> class that scrolls the items like a news reel. I added more in an edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a timer that you initialize it in `created` hook  like :

```
 created(){
      setInterval(()=>{
            axios.get('https://myapi/news_list')
               .then(response => {
                    this.news = response.data
               });
        },30000);
      }
```

**Full example for simualation**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      news: [],
      index: 0
    }
  },
  computed: {
    cptNews() {
      return this.news.map((n, i) => {
        let t = n;
        t.id = i;
        return t;
      })
    }
  },
  created() {
    setInterval(() => {

      let n = {};
      n.title = "News " + this.index;
      n.url = "https://myapi/news_list/" + this.index;
      this.news.push(n)
      this.index++;
    }, 4000);
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="description" content="Vue.delete">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.1/vue.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <ul class="news-reel">
      <li v-for="name in cptNews">
        <span>{{name.id}}</span>
        <a :href="name.url">{{name.title}}</a>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Your code should be like this (no need to `mounted`):

```
data() {
    return {
      news: []

    };
  },
  created() {
    setInterval(() => {
      axios.get('https://myapi.co/news/')
        .then(response => {
          this.news = response.data.data
        });

    }, 4000);
  }
```

Comment: This doesn't work, I just pasted your code and it does re-call the API in the chrome developer network tab every 30 seconds, but it doesn't actually re-run the v-for array or update the current v-for array.

Comment: and if you check the vue devtools what's the content of `news` array?

Comment: It is changing the array items, but the news reel is still running out items. Is there anyway to re-run the array function itself every 30 seconds so it loops?

Comment: i updated my answer by an example that simulates your use case, it should work since your news data item is reactive

Comment: This seems too make the most sense, it is adding items onto the array but not properly. Look at this screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/xRVTE39 As you can see,the news items end at 89 and then every 4 seconds it's adding the news item text but not an actual object

Comment: try a computed property called cpt_news for example based on news data item with adding i will provide you that in the answer

Comment: the provided example is a just a simulation that work like an axios call

Comment: I think I'm getting a bit confused, we are very close and I appreciate your time. The updated code creates an object and adds it onto the v-for array which is a good sign. Here is the problem https://postimg.cc/Z0h2XKq0 and here is my code: https://pastebin.com/2cqB2vhM